# Setting region of interest in simpleitk

Tags: itk

I'm trying to segment liver tumors in 3D out of body CT scans. As of now, I have a low accuracy of 70%.

My plan for raising the accuracy is to segment out the entire liver and set it as a region of interest and segment the tumor inside of the liver. However, the problem i'm having is that any thresholding method I use (neighborhood connected filter, binary threshold image filter, etc.) sets the values inside of the segmentation to white (255) and the outside to black (0).

Is there a way through which I can set the outside voxels to black but not touch the voxels inside of the liver? i've been reading through sitk documentation but i'm having trouble locating a filter that would help me do this.

Comment: Hi Ghazal. Have you gather better results into segmentation ? If you did, can you give me a little help, because I have the same task :) please write me on flaviu2@yahoo.com

Answer (score 1):

First in SimpleITK most it is common for masks and many segmentation to be binary of 0 and zeros. So please double check that the output is 0 and 255, you may want to modify your segmentation algorithm to produce this as the output.

You are can use the MaskImageFilter where you can set the value in the mask image which "black out" the grey scale image.

If both your images are the same type, and your mask image is 0 and 1 then you could simply multiply the images.